# What does the performSelector method do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, cocoa-design-patterns

What does `performSelector` do? What is the difference between creating a new `NSThread` and the `performSelector` method?

How it works and where should we use it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All of these perform the same task, that is make the `doStuff` method on `anObject` execute synchronously on the **current** thread:

```
// 1
[anObject doStuff];

// 2
[anObject performSelector:@selector(doStuff)];

// 3
objc_msgSend(anObject, @selector(doStuff));

// 4
IMP imp = [anObject methodForSelector:@selector(doStuff)];
imp(anObject, @selector(doStuff));
```

1. Is how you normally should go about to do stuff.
2. Is for dynamically dispatching a message. Use if the selector is unknown, or provided by a client, for example if you implement an target-action pattern. or if the class of `anObject` is unknown, usually used by first asking if the object has the method with `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:]`.
3. Is what no 1. is actually compiled down to. Usually never any real need to do this.
4. Cached the actual `IMP` *(implementation)* for a method, and then call it directly. Can sometimes be faster than 1. if used in a tight loop. Just remember; *premature optimization is evil*.

What you need to grasp is that in Objective-C methods are more important than classes/interfaces. Usually you do not query an object if it belongs to a particular class, or conforms to any protocol, that is for the compiler to complain about. At run-time you instead query for specific methods.

In short: **It does not matter what you are, just what you can do.**

As a convenience `NSObject` also have several siblings to `performSelector` that are asynchronios. Most notably:

- `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` - To execute the method on the current thread after a delay.
- `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` - To execute the method on a new background thread.
- `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` - To execute the method on the main thread.
- `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` - To execute the method on any thread.

The asynchronous performers all depend on a `NSRunLoop` to function. This is not something you need to worry about unless you spawn a thread yourself. If you do then you need to also run the new threads run loop. Just skip that for now.

Comment: You can use the direct method call when you don't know the class of an object -- `id foo; if ([foo respondsToSelector:@selector(bar)]) [foo bar];`  When you do need `performSelector:` is if you don't know the selector to call at compile-time (e.g. it's sent in from a different object, or it's user-selectable, etc).

Comment: (3) is sometimes useful because (2) only works with methods whose arguments are all objects and whose return type is an object or void, and which only has 0-2 arguments. For anything else you can use (3)

Comment: That comment about `methods are more important than classes/interfaces` is insightful, and explains a key difference between Objective-C and other OOP environments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`performSelector` executes a selector. In other words, it calls a method.

It is very different from running a new thread.

I think it would be best for you to read up on [selectors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocSelectors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH23-SW1).